# Serialize form with Dynamic form names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to choose one simple jquery function to serialize both oft these forms by getting form name dynamically

following jsfiddle is not working. 
[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6m2dqfv9/31/)

HTML

```
<form id="JotForm" method="post" enctype="text/plain" class="jot">
        FirstName:<input type="text" name="FirstName">
        Email:<input type="text" name="Email">

        <input id="btnFade" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>




<form id="MyForm" method="post" enctype="text/plain" class="jot">
            FirstName:<input type="text" name="FirstName">
            Email:<input type="text" name="Email">

            <input id="btnFade" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Code Part

```
 $(function () {

            $("#btnFade").bind("click", function () {

                //alert(FormId);
                //                setTimeout(function () {

                var FormId = $(".jot").attr('id');

                alert(FormId);


                var FormSerialize = $(FormId).serialize();

                console.log(FormSerialize);
            });
        });
```

Comment: This makes no sense, do you have multiple forms with the `.jot` class, and just want to target the `closest` form to the button? If so, it's just `$(this.form).serialize()` ?

Comment: Bad idea to give a form control a name of "submit" as it masks the form's submit method so you can't call it. If the action is supposed to happen when the submit button is clicked, it's likely far better to put the listener on the form's submit event since forms can be submitted without clicking the button.

Comment: Do you have "*…any number of forms…*" in the page and want to serialise them all with one function? In that case you can loop over *document.forms*, which is a collection of all forms in the document, or perhaps `$('form').each(...)`.

Comment: @RobG if i am doing wrong by applying  "control a name of "submit" as it masks the form's submit method ", what will another good approach

Comment: as @RobG suggests, what if user uses keyboard to submit? Will bypass your code

Comment: So what is good approach can you please tell me , i mean what i have to change @charlietfl

Comment: use a form  submit handler instead of a click handler on button as already suggested

Comment: can you please provide any good example, what i have to change now

Comment: `$('form.jot').submit(function(evt){ var data = $(this).serialize()...})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68441/discussion-between-jot-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
var FormSerialize = $(FormId).serialize();
```

to this

```
var FormSerialize = $("#" + FormId).serialize();
```

to make it match to element with id *FormId*.

In future when asking questions, please provide more complete example or explain more thoroughly what you are trying to achieve. I still can't understand what you are trying to achieve with this.